# SKTiled: specific tile position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, tiled

I am using [SKTiled](https://github.com/mfessenden/SKTiled).

The `SKTileLayer.tileAt(0,0)` function returns the tile at a `CGPoint`.
The `SKTileLayer.pointForCoordinate(coord: CGPoint)` does the same.

All I want is to get a Tile on the Grid (0,0) and not tiles on `CGPoint`s. That would be the first Grid in the map. How can I get the tiles in that way?

Edit: `tileAt(0,0)` returns the first Grid but if I want to change the Player position to `tileAt(0,0)` it ist not the real position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great framework, you can use the method that returns a tile coordinate for a given point in the layer:

```
SKTileLayer.coordinateForPoint(<#T##TiledLayerObject#>)
```

You can find more details to the framework official documentation [here](https://mfessenden.github.io/SKTiled/Classes/TiledLayerObject.html#/s:FC7SKTiled16TiledLayerObject18coordinateForPointFVSC7CGPointS1_)

You can also get the tile following the autocompletion as:

[image]

As you can see it return a `SKTile`

Comment: Okay this works, but why I have to addChild(player) to the Layers to get work??

Comment: No, it's not necessary, you should pay attention to the `zPosition`. To this purpose always to the [docs](https://mfessenden.github.io/SKTiled/Classes/SKTilemap.html#/s:vC7SKTiled9SKTilemap13lastZPositionV12CoreGraphics7CGFloat) you can find a useful var called `lastZposition`

Comment: If I don't do 'SKTileLayer.addChild(Player)' I get not the right position for the player node.. Whatever, do you know how to speed up the creation of the tile map? 1,6 seconds on a small map..

Comment: Don't forget that layers derived from `SKNode` so , to obtain your position you should make something like: `nodeWhereIsYourLayer.convert(yourCGPoint, to: nodeDestinationWhereIsYourPlayer)`

Comment: The tile map speed is involved by many factors: if you have many layers in a TMX map for example 3200x3200, there are many tiles/objects to render, I've a big map for example that need 2.290sec